# Android base library module implementation

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library, android-module

We are currently updating the app code, and we are splitting the code into different library modules, which are used by one application module. The problem is that the app compiling time has increased exponentially and all of a sudden the 64k multidex limit has been exceeded. Here how we are building our app:

[image]

Is the base module recompiling each time for each library module? What could be changed to improve the compile time?

Comment: Mind showing your `build.gradle`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QazFPPBz here the app module gradle

Comment: I would first recommend to change all `compile` statements to `implementation` since you appear to be using the latest Gradle plugin version. See how that goes.